How to round numbers in R with several zeros before the last digit and correctly exporting to .csv file?
I'm having problems when rounding numbers with many zeros before the last digit in R using the function round(). They appear to be correctly rounded in R the output, but when I export the rounded numbers into a .csv file using readr::write_excel_csv() they are shown as if they were not rounded. Example:
a <- c(-0.28866000000000003, 0.28372000000000003)

round(a, digits = 5)
[1] -0.28866  0.28372

Results in .csv file same as "a".
Does somebody know why?

@menarest - were you saving the values of round(a, digits = 5) anywhere? I assumed you were doing something like, b <- round(a, digits = 5) then write.csv(b). Just running round(a, digits = 5) doesnt store these values anywhere, so a is the same (unless you run a <- round(a, digits = 5)

If you want to set the number of decimals for multiple vectors that you would like to be converted into columns in your csv-file, you can use the following approach:
#----------
# Load packages
#----------
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

#----------
# Generate exemplary vectors
#----------
a <- c(-0.28866000000000003, 0.28372000000000003)
b <- c(-0.46866000000000003, 0.46372000000000003)

#----------
# Make data.frame from vectors & set decimal options for columns 
#----------
df <- data.frame (a, b) %>%
  mutate (across(1:2, .fns = function(x) {format(round(x, 5), nsmall = 5)}))

#----------
# Save as csv-file
#----------
write_excel_csv(df, "your_path/df.csv", delim = ";")


